# select2 use jquery to remove selection

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I have a select 2 box with html:

```
<div class="col-md-9">
   <select class="form-control select2" style="width: 100%;" id="project_status" name="project_status" data-placeholder="Select a project status">
      <option value="" ></option>
      <option value="Pipeline" selected>Pipeline</option>
      <option value="Started">Started</option>
      <option value="Closed">Closed</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

I have JS like this:

```
$("#project_status").select2({
    allowClear: true
});
```

I would like to get this field cleared in case I select an option in another box like this:

```
$('#project_type').change(function() {
    project_type_value_check();
  });
function project_type_value_check() {
    project_type_val = $("#project_type option:selected").val();
    if (project_type_val == "Pre-sales")
    {

$('#project_status').val(null).trigger('change');
    }
  }
```

But strangely enough, when doing that, I get very strange behavior. The first time it loads the page, the function project_type_value_check() is called and it clears well the value. But if I change the box project type to project for example then set the project status to started and then if I try to set project type to Pre-sales again, then I get the error:

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at String.replace (<anonymous>)
    at Function.fa [as find] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at n.fn.init.find (jquery.min.js:2)
    at new n.fn.init (jquery.min.js:2)
    at n (jquery.min.js:2)
    at project_type_value_check (2019:4581)
    at HTMLSelectElement.<anonymous> (2019:4626)
    at HTMLSelectElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
    at HTMLSelectElement.r.handle (jquery.min.js:3)
    at Object.trigger
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess setting the select box to null causes the issue, change it to `empty`.

```
$('#project_status').val(null).trigger('change');
```

to

```
$('#project_status').val('');
$('#project_status').select2().trigger('change');
```

```js
$("#project_status").select2({
    allowClear: true
});

$('#project_type').change(function() {
    project_type_value_check();
  });
function project_type_value_check() {
    project_type_val = $("#project_type option:selected").val();
    if (project_type_val == "Pre-sales")
    {

       $('#project_status').val('');
       $('#project_status').select2().trigger('change');
    }
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Select2 CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.7/css/select2.css">

<!-- Select2 JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.7/js/select2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<div class="col-md-9">
   <select class="form-control select2" style="width: 100%;" id="project_status" name="project_status" data-placeholder="Select a project status">
      <option value="" >--select--</option>
      <option value="Pipeline" selected>Pipeline</option>
      <option value="Started">Started</option>
      <option value="Closed">Closed</option>
   </select>
</div>

<select id="project_type">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="Pre-sales">Pre-sales</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Same error and the select2 box got visually strange in a way that it is not the same box anymore